# Django configure logging using Gunicorn

Tags: django, logging, gunicorn

Im currently trying to configure logging for my django application using Gunicorn but im not able to get my applications log into a file execpt debug is set to true

this is my settings.py logging config:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'filename': '/var/log/app/app.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
            'propagate': True
        },
    }
}
```

This is how I start my gunicorn processes:

```
gunicorn App.asgi:application \
    --workers $GUNI_WORKERS \
    --bind=127.0.0.1:8000 \
    --log-level info \
    --user=$USER \
    --capture-output \
    --disable-redirect-access-to-syslog \
    --access-logfile /var/log/app/access.log \
    --error-logfile /var/log/app/error.log \
    --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```

I basically just want to print out all logs if debug is set to true at the console and if debug is set false I only want to log to a file.

Comment: One thing that looks suspicious to me is that you configure the 'django' logger which actually only logs requests when the dev `runserver` is used. But when you start a gunicorn server, it should log requests itself due to presence of access-logfile param, and it's unclear to me why it doesn't do that. You could try to add configuration for the 'gunicorn' logger the same way as for 'django' logger and see what happens

Comment: also, 'all logs' is quite wide, if you do really mean ALL logs you would need to configure the root logger, and even that won't really make it happen because not all loggers will propagate their messages up to the root

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov Okay so you mean replacing 'django' with 'all logs' or 'gunicorn' at the 'loggers': section should do the magic? I tried that and nothing got logged anymore. The only thing that has received logs was the gunicor error.log but I expected that ...

Comment: Okay got it working, thanks again!

Comment: Resolution was https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html
And simply set 'disable_existing_loggers': False